# Delete Remote Branch

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

I need to delete a remote branch, and found this technique:

> git push origin :the_remote_branch

I tried passing it to `Network`s `Push` method in the following forms, but nothing seems to work (`options` is my login credentials):

```
_repo.Network.Push(_repo.Network.Remotes["origin"], "origin/:NewBranchForDeletion", options)  
_repo.Network.Push(_repo.Network.Remotes["origin"], ":NewBranchForDeletion", options)  
_repo.Network.Push(_repo.Network.Remotes["origin"], ":origin/NewBranchForDeletion", options)
_repo.Network.Push(_repo.Network.Remotes["origin"], ":refs/remotes/:origin/NewBranchForDeletion", options)
_repo.Network.Push(_repo.Network.Remotes["origin"], ":refs/remotes/origin/NewBranchForDeletion", options)
_repo.Network.Push(_repo.Network.Remotes["origin"], "refs/heads/:origin/NewBranchForDeletion", options)
_repo.Network.Push(_repo.Network.Remotes["origin"], "refs/heads/:NewBranchForDeletion", options)
```

And a few other options.  I cannot get it to work at all, it returns errors such as (for the ":NewBranchForDeletion" method):

> Not a valid reference "NewBranchForDeletion"

#### Update:

Thanks to @Rob for finding me this comment on LibGit2Sharp's repo: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/466#issuecomment-21076975

The first option fails with a `NullReferenceException` on `objectish`, and using `string.Empty` for `objectish` results in the error mentioned above.  The second option is what I am trying, except I am using the version with HTTPS validation:

```
repo.Network.Push(repo.Remotes["my-remote"], objectish: null, destinationSpec: "my-branch");

// Or using a refspec, like you would use with git push...
repo.Network.Push(repo.Remotes["my-remote"], pushRefSpec: ":my-branch");
```

Comment: I don't know this library, but why are you calling `Push` twice per line ? It seems to me like the solution would be along the lines of `Push(_repo.Network.Remotes["Origin"], "", "NewBranchForDeletion", options)`

Comment: Whoops, copy/pasta error.

Comment: Alternatively, do you have a working solution for a non-deleting push? Something that mimics `git push origin dev:master` ?

Comment: Yes.  `_repo.Network.Push(branch, options);`  Hmm, I'll try that.

Comment: This seems to have the solution: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/466#issuecomment-21076975

Comment: @Rob I appreciate your help, but that has exactly the same error.  In fact, the second option is what I was currently trying.  I will update my question with this.

Comment: Hmm, in that case it seems like it's a bug - might have to lodge an issue with the maintainers (since the solution at least used to work, it appears)

Comment: The maintainers watch the tag, so they should see this soon.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a test in the repo for it yet. =( https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/vNext/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/PushFixture.cs

Comment: Have you considered the `public virtual void Push(Remote remote, string pushRefSpec)` overload? Passing a `:refs/heads/branch_to_delete` refspec should work.

Comment: @nulltoken That worked!  I had tried `refs/heads/:branch_to_delete` before, which didn't work, I didn't think of that option.  Please post that as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the **[documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)**, a refspec *"Specif(ies) what destination ref to update with what source object. The format of a <refspec> parameter is an optional plus `+`, followed by the source object <src>, followed by a colon `:`, followed by the destination ref <dst>."*

It also mentions that *"Pushing an empty <src> allows you to delete the <dst> ref from the remote repository."*

Considering these above, using the `void Push(Remote remote, string pushRefSpec)` overload, and passing `:refs/heads/branch_to_delete` as the `pushRefSpec` should do the trick.